# Django; passing value from dropdown list to main page

Tags: python, django, django-templates, html.dropdownlistfor

I am still a novice to django and I have a form with a drop down menu; I am able to make a selection, but once I make that selection I need help passing it to the main page. I *think* I need to add detail to the views but I am not sure if it is there or if the detail needs to be added to the main *.html page

views.py

```
def search_device(request):
    locations = Locations.objects.all()
    context = {"locations": locations}

    for location in context['locations']:
        print(location)

    if request.method == "POST":
        location_name = request.POST.get("locations")   

    return render(request, 'example/search_device.html', context, )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', example_views.home, name="home"),
path(r'^location/$', example_views.home, name="location_name"),
path('add_location', example_views.add_location, name='add_location'),
path('add_device', example_views.add_device, name='add_device'),
path('search_device', example_views.search_device, name='search_device')]
```

device_list.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Device List</title>
</head>
<form method="post">
<body>
    <a href="add_device">Add Device</a>   <a href="add_location">Add Location</a>   <a 
     href="search_device">Search Devices</a>
<p>
<h3>Devices Go Here:</h3>
{% csrf_token %}

{% for device in devices %}
        {{device.device_name}} <br>
{% endfor %}        

<br>
<br>

<h3>Associated Locations</h3>
{% if location.location_name %}
<p> Great, you selected: {{location.location_name}}
</p>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

and search_devices.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Device List</title>
</head>
<form method="post">
<body>
<a href="add_device">Add Device</a>   <a href="add_location">Add Location</a>   <a href="search_device">Search Devices</a>
<p>
<h3>Devices Go Here:</h3>
{% csrf_token %}

{% for device in devices %}
        {{device.device_name}} <br>
{% endfor %}        

<br>
<br>

<h3>Associated Locations</h3>
{% if location.location_name %}
<p> Great, you selected: {{location.location_name}}
</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can refer this for your problem, you might need to update your html file which is select with name and option tags.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gmS4LAHTOM

Hope it helps,

Comment: I have watched this video numerous times and I think the answer is here and I need to finegle the html code some more

Answer (score 0):

the views.py needed this additional code:

```
 def device_list(request):
    location_name = request.POST.get('location_name')
    my_devices = Devices.objects.filter(location= Locations.objects.get(location_name = location_name))
```

context = {"devices": my_devices,
           "locations": location_name}


return render(request, 'example/device_list.html',context)

the query shown at my_devices above was what was needed to pass into the template